# Value not saved after edit ng repeat angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a little trouble with angular. I have a td element. Initially, it is populated with the value 'item.comparedProducts.value'. When I click on it, it let me edit the value. I want to remain saved after I refresh it. If I delete the ng-repeat, it's successful. Or if I delete the code after

```
 ng-init.. =false; (item <- this)
```

there is no values initially, brought from comparedProducts, but if I edit the label and then refresh, the value is saved.
Do you have some ideas how to resolve this simpler? Or some helpful information to share with me about it? Lots of thanks

```
 <tr class="col-new3">
        <td>Value</td>
        <td ng-repeat="item in list"
            ng-init="editCorrectValue = false; item.correctedMonthlyValue=item.comparedProducts.value"
            data-ng-click="editCorrectValue = true; focusInput($event)" class="add-comma is-editable">
            <input ng-blur="editCorrectValue = false" ng-show="editCorrectValue" data-ng-model="item.correctedMonthlyValue" type="number">
            <span ng-show="!editCorrectValue">{{'{{ item.correctedMonthlyValue }}'}}</span>
        </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: the `angular` tag is for Angular 2 - this looks like AngularJS try tagging with `angularjs` instead

Comment: ?? My mistake when I set the tag...